# Splitting string by whitespace, hyphen and "ab cd"

Tags: java, regex, split, delimiter

```
c = "abc ab cd-abc-abc";

 String[] cinput = c.split("(?<=[ ])|(-)|(?<=ab cd)|(?=ab cd)");
```

I want to split string c like this (order is important as well):

```
 cinput[0] = "abc " (notice the space)
 cinput[1] = "ab cd"
 cinput[2] = "abc"
 cinput[3] = "abc"
```

Another example:

c = "abc-abc abc ab cd-ab-cd";

```
 cinput[0] = "abc" 
 cinput[1] = "abc "
 cinput[2] = "abc "
 cinput[3] = "ab cd"
 cinput[4] = "ab"
 cinput[5] = "cd"
```

Delimiters " ", "-" and "ab cd". The way I do it "ab cd" becomes two array elements "ab" and "cd", but I want them to be together in one element.

Any ideas on how to solve this and what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: I got the part  for whitespace and hypen, but can you explain the third part?

Comment: Whenever "ab cd" appears in a string I want to split it there, but keep "ab cd" in one array element.

Comment: Your logic seems complicated and irregular enough that I doubt any standard functions are going work for you. You'll likely have to process and split the string by hand.

Comment: What about doing it in two steps? First the "ab cd" part and then the whitespace and hyphens?

Comment: @user1820881 As ean said. Its not possible in one regex. However you can go around split string by `[\\s-]` and check adjacent string for your convenience or something else depends how you want to handle.

Comment: Is it you want "ab cd" to be "unsplittable"? Or is it that you want hyphens to take precedence over spaces for splitting, so if the *next* split is a hyphen, don't split the a space?

Comment: Unsplittable, yeah.  I need "ab cd" to always be splitted into one element.

Answer (score 2):

Since you have a white space in your delimiter text, as well as white space as one of your delimiters, you might have to do your split in multiple steps with extra logic

1) split on "-"  that will produce: { "abc ab cd", "adc", "abc" }
2) check for your text field
  if ( text[].contains("ab cd") )
     - remove "ab cd" from text and save
 => {"abc ", "abc", "abc"} and {"ab cd"}

3) split non-saved text on white space and combine your two sets

Comment: I need the elements to be ordered the same way in the array as in string c though. I'm not sure how I would combine them into the correct order. The combinations of abc, ab cd, hyphen and space will not be the same in every string c.

Comment: @user1820881 This is a problem. If you can tell us what exactly you want with some more input and outputs.

Comment: @user1820881 I dont think it will done through regex for generalized solution as you have no regular pattern. Moreover you also want to split by space and at same time you want to keep them. I will suggest you to do the String Operations on it.